# I want to obtain the highest % of the category "sex" in 2018 and that also shows what is the gender of that percentage

Tags: sql-server

I put max with strata_name, but I'm not sure if it was the correct decision.

```
SELECT Year, Strata, FORMAT(max([percentage]/100000), 'P') Npercentage, Max(Strata_Name) as gender
FROM [dbo].[Depression_in_California] 
WHERE Strata = 'Sex' 
GROUP BY Year, Strata, Strata_Name
ORDER BY Year desc;
```

Here is the image

[image]

Comment: What is your question here, exactly? Also, I must admit, `%` is a poor name a for column; give them meaningful names that don't need to be delimit identified. Also it's recommended to avoid the function `FORMAT` most of the time; it is known to perform poorly. In this case, you should really be leaving the presentation layer to format the value, and you should be passing a `decimal`/`numeric` to the presentation layer, not a `varchar`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, instead of format what should I use?

Comment: You already `GROUP BY` `Strata_Name`, you don't need to apply `MAX()` on it

Comment: *"instead of format what should I use?"* I tell you in my comment...

Comment: @Freddmo If possible, upload an output sample in Excel so that we can write a query based on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row-numbering and a windowed sum for this

```
SELECT
  Year,
  Strata,
  gender
FROM (
    SELECT
      Year,
      'Sex' AS Strata,
      FORMAT(COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY Year), 'P') Npercentage,
      Strata_Name as gender,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM [dbo].[Depression_in_California] 
    WHERE Strata = 'Sex' 
    GROUP BY Year, Strata_Name
) dic
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Year desc;
```